# VI - Copy search matches

Tags: vi

I have a log file like the one below that I would like to copy just the matching search results to a new file.  I am trying to do a search for all of the item barcodes listed below 
they all start with 312600 including the ones that have the numbers wrapped to the next line aand copy just these barcodes to another file.

Thanks for all your help

```
7/9/2012,11:09:14 Station: 0079 Request: Sequence #: 54 Command: Charge Item 
Part B
station login user access:CIRC  station library:MAIN  station login clearance:NO
NE  station user's user ID:MAINCIRC  item ID:31260016399431  user ID:21660009335
807  Client type: see client_types.h for values:3  rs:Y  jz:1  user block 
override:YES  Max length of transaction response:3000000  

7/9/2012,11:19:15 Station: 0079 Request: Sequence #: 56 Command: Charge Item 
Part B
station login user access:CIRC  station library:MAIN  station login clearance:NO
NE  station user's user ID:MAINCIRC  item ID:31260016121751  user ID:21760000705
807  Client type: see client_types.h for values:3  rs:Y  jz:1  user block 
override:YES  Max length of transaction response:3000000  

7/27/2012,07:45:45 Station: 0040 Request: Sequence #: 10 Command: Renew User 
Part B
station login user access:PUBLIC  station login clearance:NONE  station 
library:MAIN  Client type: see client_types.h for values:1  item ID:312600161880
08  call number:F HOF  copy number:2  user ID:25210000905805  WWW CGI program 
name:93  transaction in goback unless "N":N  Wt:ELib
```

Comment: First off, what have you yourself tried?

Comment: /31260[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]

Answer (score 0):

Try using **grep** or **egrep**, like so:

`grep -e '312600\d*' -o log_file > output_file`

Output from your snippet:

> 31260016399431
>   31260016121751
>   312600161880

With **pcregrep**, you can include the carriage returns, but I don't see how to remove them yet (I saw something about using **tr** but I don't have time to investigate that right now).

`pcregrep -Moe '312600[\n\d]*' log_file > output_file`

> 31260016399431
>   31260016121751
>   312600161880
>   08

Unfortunately, this has the line break still in place, but maybe you can pipe this through something else to remove that.